# Regexp to extract postcodes from CSV address data

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex

I have CSV data with one of the fields containing customer-submitted addresses, with some entries only containing postcodes, not all formatted the same, whilst some contain addresses and postcodes.

e.g.

"Dt29bu"

"hp17 9tn"

"Junk address, Barnet, London N12 0QF"

"S8 0ZW"

I would like to be able to extract just the postcodes into a separate field and have them formatted such that:

-if they are 5 characters long, in format XX XXX

-if they are 6 characters long, in format XXX XXX

-if they are 7 characters long, in format XXXX XXX

I can then convert these to longitude/latitude.

I am using OSX so Excel-VBA Regex functionality is not available to me. What's the best way for me to go about this?

Comment: Make friends with `grep` and `awk` first. `man grep` and `man awk` will give you an overview of what they can do. Next, extract only the CSV field that contains the postcode into a working CSV file that is lean, mean and relatively free of extraneous info.  Finally, divide and conquer: extract the easiest-to-recognize entries first, and remove those entries from the working copy of your CSV file.  Then work on extracting the next-easiest group of codes, and again, remove those from the CSV file.  If you're new to this type of text processing, don't try to hit a home run.  Do it in small steps.

Comment: @Jim L.  

Thanks for this great advice! I'm nearly there, using a regexp I found online, which I have tested in this online utility: https://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp

So I'm doing:

`awk '/([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})/ {print $0 }' file.csv`

The issue is it's only returning addresses with postcodes which are concatenated e.g. DN110FQ but not RM3 0RR. In the online utility it's behaving as expected but not in terminal. Any idea why?

Comment: @JimL. [[:space:]]? has done the trick in place of the \s? which is not recognised by Grep :)

Comment: Nice job doing the research to find out what was broken!